# GUI shows that Windows Defender Firewall is enabled, but netsh does not. Why?

Tags: windows-10, firewall

I'm on a Windows 10 laptop that's managed by my company.

The GUI:

- I click Start and open Settings.
- I open "Update & Security".
- I open "Windows Security" on the left.
- In the list, I open "Firewall & network protection".
- I see that all three firewalls are set to on: domain network, private network, and public network.

PowerShell:

- I start PowerShell as an administrator.
- I run: `netsh advfirewall show allprofiles state`
- I see that all three firewalls are set to off: domain, private, and public profile settings.

Why are these different?

Comment: "I'm on a Windows 10 laptop that's managed by my company."   <-- The firewall settings are set by your company and you need to ask them.  On a non-domain machine the firewall is ON.

Answer (score 5):

According to this article: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/4d8678e2-5653-4fd2-b275-62e0e7008ff9/conflicting-display-of-windows-firewall-setting-from-gui-and-netsh-advfirewall?forum=winserverGP

Windows Firewall has mutliple configuration stores. One is for Group Policy and one is for local. The policy that is actually applied is a result of a merge of these stores (how they are merged depends on what options are set in Group Policy).

This is shown correctly by the Control Panel, netsh shows the configuration in the local store.